# How to install all existing media codecs?

Tags: codecs, media

How to install all possible media codecs from console?

Is there a way to load and save them for some cases without Internet connection?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### **UPDATE:** 2017-Jan

**For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 16.10 (12.04 or later)**

update the repos:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install CURL tool

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

load VideoLAN repository

```
curl https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list
sudo apt-get update
```

install VLC and Mplayer, and their support elements

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-data browser-plugin-vlc mplayer2
```

If still using **14.04 LTS** (or earlier), then:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-pulse
```

install remaining Ubuntu 'restricted extras' (146 MB when installed, skip if space is critical)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you are **NOT** already using **16.04 LTS** (or later), force (manually) install the *three* key elements for full DVD support:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
```

Comment: didn't get. for what we adding medibuntu rep? to get wide codecs range?

Comment: ubuntu did'nt include some codec's due to licence issues , mediaubuntu team packed such codecs

Comment: see: http://medibuntu.org/ "*Medibuntu is a packaging project dedicated to distributing software that cannot be included in Ubuntu for various reasons, related to geographical variations in legislation regarding intellectual property, security and other issues:*"

Comment: This answer could need an update (for Ubuntu 16.04). `E: Package 'vlc-plugin-pulse' has no installation candidate` and `sudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found`

Comment: Package 'vlc-plugin-pulse' in now included (as of 2015-11-17) in **vlc** main. See: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/arm64/vlc-plugin-pulse

Comment: probably we should use https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc instead of that unencrypted key?

Answer (score 9):

Yep, I had this problem when I switched to Ubuntu a year ago lol. I only know how to install them. I then made a mirror of my Linux installation as it's a bit more complex than using just the Ubuntu Desktop. I use a Server Thin Client Environment.

Anyway the command to install codecs you need is

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-bad-multiverse
```

You may want to check if there is a later version of gstreamer available. The last one worked well for me and all my videos played so I stuck to this version (0.10)

I'm sure there is a way to save it too but hopefully someone will answer your the second part of your question here

Comment: you can download them from the gstreamer website. Click [link](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't thinks your codec list if full enough. I need almost all existing codecs.

Comment: check out this Post installation guide. It has details on installing codecs in the Multimedia section. I hope this helps [link](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/linux/330-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin-post-installation-guide#ubuntu-multimedia)

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04, except I had to remove `gstreamer0.10-bad-multivers`

Answer (score 7):

To install all the *default media codecs for Ubuntu, run this command in the **terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

You will then be asked for your password (your password will **NOT** show up in the terminal, but I promise you it is there)

Press [Enter]

When prompted, press [Enter] (again)

Once the process is complete, you're good to go!

*Generally you have a choice to download and install them during initial instillation, but you can always install them this way as well after the fact

**To open the terminal, right click on any empty workspace, and select "Open Terminal"

Answer (score 5):

Install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` for most of the codecs. To install it, click on the below image:
[image: Install via the software center]

Install and run [aptoncd [image: Install aptoncd]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptoncd) to backup all the packages you have downloaded; you can reuse them using `aptoncd` in any computer.

Comment: I really need all the codecs. How Can I obtain rare ones?

Comment: i think all the codecs would come with restricted extras, still you can search in the "software centre" for any other codecs left to be installed. if you are a music professional , you can install "ubuntustudio desktop" it will fetch all the required packages for art-music professionals.