# How to install codecs offline

Tags: codecs

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 version earlier, but when I want to play MP3 or any kind of media, a message shows that you have not installed codec, decoder for these type of file.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to check out [this question on media codecs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171026/how-to-install-all-existing-media-codecs) and then add to your post if none of the options work, hope this helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install MP3 codecs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528527/how-do-i-install-mp3-codecs) and [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the codecs are not installed when you install Ubuntu. If you need to install them on a computer that doesn't have internet connection, you have to use a tool like Apt on cd ([aptoncd.sourceforge.net](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net)) on a computer with internet connection to create a repository disk media and use it to install the packages on the computer without internet connection.