# How do I install media codecs?

Tags: windows, mp3, format-conversion

What is the easiest way to install all the media codec available for Ubuntu? I am having issues with multiple applications prompting me to install codecs before they can play my files.

Comment: What "current alternatives" are you speaking of?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/507525/158442

Comment: Why did you tag your question [tag:format-conversion]?

Comment: I don't know formating here

Comment: See [How to install all existing media codecs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171026/how-to-install-all-existing-media-codecs)

Answer (score 2):

If you are missing Codecs, you can try this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

That should install the missing packages for multimedia.

Comment: murtaza@murtaza-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras
murtaza@murtaza-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: I edited this with a revised command for you to try.

Answer (score 1):

MP3 is an audio format. Ubuntu can play both out of the box. Use Rhythmbox Music Player for audio and Ubuntu's default video player.

You can also use VLC which plays both.

Comment: But I am not able to install VLC media player, say 'code' Package dependencies couldn't be resolved 'code'

Comment: Alternatives like VLC media player and Rhythmbox Music Player

Comment: Correct Ubuntu plays all the popular media formats out of the box, if you don't like the default players, there are many other alternatives like Gnome Player, SM Player, Audacious, XBMC, etc.
That's just a small sample of the popular ones, there are of course many many more to choose from.

Comment: I am looking for alternatives because I am having trouble in installing VLC and while running MP3 files from Rhythmbox player, it says, to install codecs,