# Sound problem with playing media in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, multimedia

My system is Ubuntu 16.04. Before, everything worked well, but now when I want to play a media - sound, video, etc. - using VLC, there isn't any sound. The system notifications have sound.

I reinstalled VLC, but the problem still exists.

I don't know  what's wrong with it.

I have another OS, Windows 7, in that everything has sound. So the problem is not from the hardware of my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked the volume mixer in the system tray, while VLC is running, to make sure that the volume for it isn't turned down or off? Just left click on the speaker icon.

In addition, you could open a console and run: `alsamixer` to check volume settings there.

Finally open your system settings and revise the settings of your reproduction devices... There might be an issue there.

If all that fails, please try these links:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1770283
- [Why do the video players make no sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638446/why-do-the-video-players-make-no-sound)

Hope this helps,

Ben

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the 3 proposed solutions. I couldn't find any problem in the setting.

Comment: Is this just for VLC or for other players as well?

Comment: It is for "Totem" too. I just have these 2 installed.

Comment: check http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1770283 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/638446/why-do-the-video-players-make-no-sound to see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Glad it helped. I have added the links to my answer.

Comment: In VLC, I went to Audio -> Audio Device and selected (or re-selected, I'm not sure) Built in Audio Analoge Stereo ( with the help of the second link above).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Audio** > **Audio Devices** > There is 2 devices **HDMI Audio** and **Built in Analog Audio**. select or changed it to **Analog Audio** and all players will fixed after that change.