# VLC does not support the audio or video format "hevc"

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, mkv, hevc

I'm trying to run an .mkv video, I even installed the codecs from this page: [How to install all existing media codecs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171026/how-to-install-all-existing-media-codecs)

But still keep getting this error on VLC player:

No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "hevc". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

It plays only the audio.

Help please?

Comment: Which version of vlc are you using?It sould automatically work if you are using 2.1.2

Answer (score 12):

There is a VLC plugin available for HEVC playaback. To play H.265/HEVC videos with VLC player in Ubuntu OS we need to install vlc-plugin-libde265 module.

Use following commands to install vlc-plugin-libde265

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265`

Details can be found here: [GStreamer plugin for 4K H.265/HEVC video streaming](http://www.libde265.org/blog/2014/02/22/gstreamer-4k-h265-hevc-plugin/)

more info on numerous distros can be found [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265

Comment: @workflow  Thank you. I edited answer to include repository & update commands.