# Anyone else getting errors when installing codecs with 16.10?

Tags: codecs, 16.10

If I click the box to install codecs during install I'll get a system has encountered a problem error, no details, by the time I go to create my user.  If I install codecs after an install it errors out too.  I see the following in a terminal window when doing the later.

```
"W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/arial32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)"
```

So this would appear to be a privilege problem but unsure how to correct that post install and certainly haven't a clue how to elevate my user before one is even created during install.

Comment: Have you prefixed the post-install command with `sudo`?

Comment: I followed the link on step 4 here, http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/10/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-10  I am unsure how to do that with an elevated privilege.  Also unsure how to prove this is the error I get during the initial install of the OS but if I don't check the install codecs, I can install without a problem so it seems to point in that direction.

Comment: Please see this answer for how to install the codecs: http://askubuntu.com/a/171084/518562