# mp4 files not playing in OEM-installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: video

Ubuntu 14.04 is pre-installed on my dell laptop. I am trying to run mp4 files but it's not playing. It's asking me to install a package. 
I checked for VLC player and it's not installed.

Comment: VLC is almost essential for sound playing, because it has compatibility with every type of media. Just `sudo apt install vlc`and here you are! You must enable universe repositories at update-manager

Comment: Also: [How to install all existing media codecs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/171026/158442)

Answer (score 3):

[VLC](http://videolan.org) is essential for media playing, because it is compatible with a widely range of media types, including mp4. Just install it using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Don't forget to enable universe repository at your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. To do it, just check correspondent box at update-manager:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

VLC is a good multimedia player.

It is also valuable for playing multimedia to install the 'restricted extras'. In standard Ubuntu you can do it with the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This package will bring several codecs and other tools, that will make also other multimedia players work (not only VLC).